# Can someone help me solve this system of congruences?

Tags: number-theory

I'm a little new to congruences but I think I have it right.
I started with the following congruences:
$19x \equiv 5 \pmod{2}$ 
$19x \equiv 5 \pmod{3}$ 
$19x \equiv 5 \pmod{5}$ 
$19x \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$

I was able to simplify it to be: 
$x \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ 
$x \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ 
$x \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ 
$x \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$

What do I do from here though? I don't know what to do now.

Comment: How do you get $$x\equiv0\pmod{5}$$

Comment: Also, are you familiar with the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: I missed a congruence when I wrote the question sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\,\ 2,3,5,7\mid 19x\!-\!5\iff 210\mid 19x\!-\!5,\,$ since $\,{\rm lcm}(2,3,5,7) = 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7 = 210.\,$

${\rm mod}\ 210\!:\ \dfrac{1}{19} \equiv \dfrac{-209}{19}\equiv\dfrac{-190-19}{19}\equiv \color{#c00}{-11}\ $ so $\ 19x\equiv 5\!\!\overset{\ \times\ \color{#c00}{-11}}\iff x\equiv -55\equiv 155$

Answer (score 0):

Your reductions are correct, though you shouldn't be including $x \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.

We will use the Chinese Remainder Theorem here. The first thing we do is calculate the product of the moduli: $M = 210$. Now we take terms as follows:

Given congruences of the form $x \equiv a_{i} \pmod{m_{i}}$, we generate terms $a_{i} * \frac{M}{m_{i}} * (\frac{M}{m_{i}}^{-1} \pmod{m_{i}})$.

So we have initially $x \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$. So $a_{i} = 1$, $\frac{210}{2} = 105$, and $105^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod 2$. So our first term is $105$.

For our second term, we look at $2 * 70 * (70^{-1} \pmod{3}) = 140$.

For our third term, we look at $1 * 30 * (30^{-1} \pmod{7}) = 120$.

Now we solve $x \equiv 105 + 140 + 120 \pmod{210}$.

You can find more on the Chinese Remainder Theorem here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/238017-chinese-remainder-theorem-tutorial/

Comment: I missed one when I wrote the question sorry :(

Comment: The question has been updated. Include $x\equiv0\pmod{5}$ now.

Comment: @user140667 Also, see the current solution(which works for your previous question) gather the general idea, and then apply it to your question. Best way to learn.

Comment: I've updated my answer. User140667- Since $x \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$, I've omitted that term since it would be $0$. Hope this helps!

Sabyasachi- I get comment notifications and was in the process of updating. Reminders are unnecessary. Thanks! ;)

Comment: I got x = 145 (mod210) am I right?

Comment: Check your arithmetic. You're a bit off. Also, you can check your work on the original congruences. Do you get the right answer by plugging in $145$ to the original congruences?

Comment: One doesn't *solve* $\,x\equiv 105+140+120,\,$ rather one computes it, or reduces or normalizes it.

Comment: Finally. I got 155 (mod 210). How about that? :) The problem was, I wrote down x=5mod7 on my paper (which is wrong) but I wrote x=1mod7 on here. Funny how things like that work eh?

Comment: @user140667 That's correct - see my answer for a method simpler than brute-force CRT.

Comment: @ml0105 Actually I was typing my comment, when OP posted his, and I had already clicked enter on reflex. I considered deleting, but thought that might be confusing since you would get the notification anyway. Cheers.